# 503 Service unavailable Apache, Magento 2, Varnish, Redis

Tags: apache, ubuntu, magento, varnish

i have a digitalocean droplet 1 click Magento 2 install that has Redis & Varnish, and because varnish uses port 80 so installing SSL is a little bit tricky, that i had to include http --http-01-port 8080 so it works, today was supposed to be the certificate renewal but it didn't auto renew and i received site not secured error, so i logged in to the server and i renewed the certificate using

```
certbot --force-renewal  --http-01-port 8080 -d domainname.com,www.domainname.com
```

and the renewal is done, but after i did that i'm now receiving 503 Service unavailable with varnish disabled and with varnish enabled i receive Error 503 backend fetch failed

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName domainname.com
        ServerAlias www.domainname.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pub

        <Directory /var/www/html/pub>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domainname.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domainname.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

my apache error log shows

```
[Sun Sep 25 12:08:54.528941 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 51038] [client IP:19124] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

the 503 error showing even in Phpmyadmin, so i guess this error has nothing to do with Magento

what could be the issue?

**Edit:**

sudo varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"

```
*   << Request  >> 2
-   Begin          req 1 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1664111575.119591 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1664111575.119591 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 7840 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vYXIvY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9sb2dpblBvc3QvcmVmZXJlci9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZaVzR2WTIxekwyNXZjbTkxZEdVdmFXNWtaWGd2ZFdWdVl5OWhTRkl3WTBoTk5reDVPRE5sVjBab1lYazFhbUl5TU
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html, application/rss+xml, application/atom+xml, text/xml, text/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.40
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.40
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.40, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vYXIvY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9sb2dpblBvc3QvcmVmZXJlci9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZaVzR2WTIxekwyNXZjbTkxZEdVdmFXNWtaWGd2ZFdWdVl5OWhTRkl3WTBoTk5reDVPRE5sVjBab1lYazFhbUl5TU
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 3 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1664111575.120014 0.000422 0.000422
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:12:55 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 2
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 2
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1664111575.120075 0.000484 0.000061
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 278
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1664111575.120135 0.000544 0.000060
-   ReqAcct        791 0 791 269 278 547
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 3
--  Begin          bereq 2 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1664111575.119704 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vYXIvY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9sb2dpblBvc3QvcmVmZXJlci9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZaVzR2WTIxekwyNXZjbTkxZEdVdmFXNWtaWGd2ZFdWdVl5OWhTRkl3WTBoTk5reDVPRE5sVjBab1lYazFhbUl5TU
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html, application/rss+xml, application/atom+xml, text/xml, text/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.40, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 3
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1664111575.119731 0.000027 0.000027
--  Timestamp      Error: 1664111575.119732 0.000028 0.000000
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:12:55 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         278
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End

*   << Request  >> 5
-   Begin          req 4 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1664111597.397651 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1664111597.397651 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 47420 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /robots.txt
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/plain,text/html,*/*
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.66.47
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.66.47
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.66.47, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /robots.txt
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 6 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1664111597.397807 0.000156 0.000156
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:13:17 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 5
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 5
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1664111597.397819 0.000167 0.000011
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 278
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1664111597.397856 0.000205 0.000037
-   ReqAcct        342 0 342 269 278 547
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 6
--  Begin          bereq 5 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1664111597.397716 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /robots.txt
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/plain,text/html,*/*
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.66.47, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 6
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1664111597.397732 0.000015 0.000015
--  Timestamp      Error: 1664111597.397733 0.000016 0.000000
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:13:17 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         278
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End

*   << Request  >> 32770
-   Begin          req 32769 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1664111601.616549 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1664111601.616549 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 47432 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /fr/stores/store/redirect/___store/en/___from_store/fr/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vZW4vY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZZWEl2YUc5MWMyVm9iMnhrTG1oMGJXd19jRDB6L3Byb2R1Y3QvNDEzLw,,/
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html, application/rss+xml, application/atom+xml, text/xml, text/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.22
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.22
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.22, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /fr/stores/store/redirect/___store/en/___from_store/fr/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vZW4vY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZZWEl2YUc5MWMyVm9iMnhrTG1oMGJXd19jRDB6L3Byb2R1Y3QvNDEzLw,,/
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 32771 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1664111601.616769 0.000220 0.000220
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:13:21 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 32770
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 32770
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1664111601.616782 0.000233 0.000013
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 282
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1664111601.616807 0.000258 0.000024
-   ReqAcct        615 0 615 269 282 551
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 32771
--  Begin          bereq 32770 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1664111601.616650 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /fr/stores/store/redirect/___store/en/___from_store/fr/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vZW4vY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZZWEl2YUc5MWMyVm9iMnhrTG1oMGJXd19jRDB6L3Byb2R1Y3QvNDEzLw,,/
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html, application/rss+xml, application/atom+xml, text/xml, text/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.22, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 32771
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1664111601.616665 0.000014 0.000014
--  Timestamp      Error: 1664111601.616665 0.000015 0.000000
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:13:21 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         282
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End

*   << Request  >> 8
-   Begin          req 7 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1664111607.366603 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1664111607.366603 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 13422 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vYXIvY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZaVzR2WW5KaGJtUXZhRzU2TG1oMGJXdywvcHJvZHVjdC8xMTMwLw,,/
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html, application/rss+xml, application/atom+xml, text/xml, text/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.5
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.5
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.5, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vYXIvY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZaVzR2WW5KaGJtUXZhRzU2TG1oMGJXdywvcHJvZHVjdC8xMTMwLw,,/
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 9 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1664111607.366837 0.000233 0.000233
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:13:27 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 8
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 8
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.4)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1664111607.366855 0.000252 0.000018
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 278
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1664111607.366893 0.000289 0.000037
-   ReqAcct        610 0 610 269 278 547
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 9
--  Begin          bereq 8 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1664111607.366701 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly83eWFhay5jb20vYXIvY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0hNNkx5ODNlV0ZoYXk1amIyMHZaVzR2WW5KaGJtUXZhRzU2TG1oMGJXdywvcHJvZHVjdC8xMTMwLw,,/
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html, application/rss+xml, application/atom+xml, text/xml, text/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: domain.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 185.191.171.5, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 9
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1664111607.366723 0.000021 0.000021
--  Timestamp      Error: 1664111607.366724 0.000022 0.000001
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:13:27 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         278
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"` to your original question. I'd like to see the log output when Varnish returns a "backend fetch failure"? It might show more details on the reason of the failure.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn, added, i had to replace the actual domain name with domainname.com so you should know

Answer (score 0):

### Backend unhealthy

I noticed the following log line in your log output:

```
--  FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
```

This means that your backend is administratively set to an unhealthy state because too many health checks failed.

> See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/troubleshooting-varnish/#backend-health-monitoring for a handy tutorial about backend health monitoring in Varnish

You could run `sudo varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health` to validate this and see how many failures have taken place.

### Backend health criteria

The criteria for the backend to be considered healthy in your configuration are the following:

- The backend should connect within 3.5 seconds *(default value)*
- The first byte should be received within 600 seconds after sending the backend request
- The response should have a `200` status code
- 5 *(the threshold value)* out of 10 *(the window value)* health checks should succeed

### Debugging the health check probe

In your VCL code `/health_check.php` is the endpoint of the health check probe. Run the following command to debug what's going on when Varnish loads it every 5 seconds:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/health_check.php'"
```

You can add the output of this command to your question and I'll help you debug.

However, if the returned status code for these health checks is `404`, it means you're using the wrong URL and you need to fix that first.

> See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/#fixing-the-backend-health-checks-for-magento-24 for a tutorial section about a common mistake in Magento when using `health_check.php`.